# Amana washer floods my floor on warm/cold cycle

Tags: washer

My Amana washer model#NTW4650YQ0 works fine on cold/cold but spills onto the floor when on warm/cold cycle. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The washer has an internal leak.  It is on the "hot" water line, and only leaks when the washer is trying to fill the tub.  That places the leak past the solenoid valve but before the washer tub.

The answer is get the owner's manual and pop the back off the washer and look for problems.  Could be a simple as a loose clamp, or as bad as a cracked solenoid valve assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get past the solenoid valve, hot and cold water share a common hose. So I would suspect the solenoid valve has a leak on the hot side.